# How to forward existing domain name to AWS application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, domain-name

I have deployed an application with Amazon's Elastic Beanstalk service, now it runs in `http://sample-env-1.abcde.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/home`, and now I want to point my domain name (registered with name.com) to this application. I created a hosted zone with Route 53, which gives me 4 namespaces, is it enough to add these records in my domain registrar's console?

I feel like I'm missing something since I didn't tell which application should this hosted zone be relevant to (since I can have multiple applications). How do I do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of doing it is right.

Type the domain name in Hosted Zone of Amazon Route 53 Management console.
And from your domain provider console point your domain to your Elastic Beanstalk environment namespace. Amazon will handle the rest, if the setup is done correctly.

As stated in the manual:

> When an Amazon Route 53 DNS server receives a name request for your
>   custom domain name, it resolves to the elasticbeanstalk.com subdomain,
>   which resolves to the public DNS name of your Elastic Load Balancing
>   load balancer, which relays requests to the instances in your
>   environment.

Please refer to the Elastic Beanstalk manual for more information: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customdomains.html

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am checking that manual too. But I'm still confused. I can have more than one EB application, how does Route 53 understand which domain name (namespace?) is relevant to which application? Should I add a record set, and how? :)

Comment: That you can resolve in the CNAME record in your Amazon Route 53. In the value part type in your application.elasticbeanstalk.com, and Amazon Route 53 can resolve which application the request being processed

Comment: I tried to add a CNAME record set and I got this error: `RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name example.com. is not permitted at apex in zone example.com.` **Edit**: it worked (I guess) when I added `www` in the box in front of "Name" (example.com). Does this sound correct? Now I add those 4 NS records to name.com and it's done?

Comment: For some reason i think you may have some confusion about how elastic beanstalk works. You setup your environment to run different applications. The URL you have posted is of the environment and not the application running in it. You also need to setup your application url in your Amazon Route 53 console in the CNAME record. I believe you have already done this part, based on what you have commented.

Comment: Yes, just add those 4 NS records to name.com and its done. But for the NS record do not add www. It will resolve it automatically.

Comment: I'm a complete newbie to almost all of this (AWS and DNS things) :) I have 2 records (NS and SOA) that were auto-generated and contain `Name: "example.com"`, and my new record (CNAME) looks like this: `{Name: "www.example.com", Value: "http://myapp..elasticbeanstalk.com"}`. OK, I guess it's correct now :) Thanks again for your help.

Comment: That seems right. This means that www.example.com is pointing to your app (myapp), which is http://myapp.elasticbeanstalk.com